# Loading 64-bit module to a 32-bit kernel using insmod

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

Is is possible to load a `.ko` file (kernel object file) which was compiled in 64-bit processor system into 32 bit processor system?

Actually I am getting following error when I issue the insmod command in my system:

```
insmod: error inserting 'be2net.ko': -1 Invalid module format
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to run 64-bit code in a 32-bit system. Depending on the requirements, the reverse can be true (running 32-bit software or libraries in a 64-bit system), but a 32-bit architecture cannot understand 64-bit code. You will need to compile the module on your system.

First download the kernel source from [kernel.org](http://kernel.org). Then extract, and cd into

```
linux/drivers/net/benet
```

Once there, type (as your regular user)

```
make
```

and then

```
sudo insmod be2net.ko
```

That should work for you.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible to load 64-bit modules to a 32-bit kernel, and that is why you are getting an error. The reason is that 64 and 32-bit program have an incompatible ABI (e.g. different calling conventions). That is also the reason 64-bit applications can't be linked with 32-bit libraries, for example.

Note that insmod generally gives vague error message. For a more detailed message look at the output of `dmesg`.

Answer (score 1):

The processor where it was compiled matters not at all.  The compiler and compiler options do matter.  If it was compiled FOR a 64-bit processor, it cannot run on a 32-bit processor, because it uses a different instruction set.

However, a 64-bit processor can run a cross-compiler and create 32-bit binaries.  It is unlikely that you've done this.